Consequence of Banach Alaoglu Theorem
The Banach Alaoglu theorem states:
Let $\mathcal{Z}$ be a banach space. The closed unit ball
$\{Z^{\ast}\in\mathcal{Z}^{\ast}:\|Z^{\ast}\|_{\ast}\leq1\}$ is compact in the weak$\ast$ topology of $\mathcal{Z}^{\ast}$.
Then in the lecture notes I am using there is the following consequence:
It follows that any bounded (in the dual norm $\|\cdot\|_{\ast}$) and weakly$\ast$ closed subset of $\mathcal{Z}^{\ast}$ is weakly$\ast$ compact.
Now, I do not understand why this follows:
1.) Why can we transfer it to any subset of $\mathcal{Z}^{\ast}$ (that is bounded and closed of course) when the theorem only gives us the compactness of the unit ball? I.e. we would need something more general like $\|Z^{\ast}\|_{\ast}\leq M$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$ instead of just $\|Z^{\ast}\|_{\ast}\leq1$
2.) Why do we need boundedness and closedness (and even in two different topologies)?

Scalar multiplication is a homeomorphism, so the closed ball of any radius in the dual space is weak* compact.

@WhileIAm thanks for your comment. But this would imply that only sets that are somehow symmetric about the origin would be an option?

I’m not clear where you’re getting this implication from. Do you mind explaining your reasoning?

So ${Z^{\ast}\in\mathcal{Z}^{\ast}:|Z^{\ast}|{\ast}\leq1}$ is the unit ball, i.e., the ball centered at 0 with radius 1. Then when scalar multiplying this set by $M$ we get${Z^{\ast}\in\mathcal{Z}^{\ast}:|Z^{\ast}|{\ast}\leq M}$ which is a ball centered at 0 with radius $M$.

a closed subset of a compact space is compact

@guest1 What do you mean by only sets symmetric about the origin are an option? Do you mean that they should be the only weak- compact sets?

@guest1 A closed subset of a compact set is compact. So if $A \subset \mathcal{Z}^\ast$ is weak$^\ast$ closed and bounded, then it is a closed subset of the compact set ${Z^\ast \in \mathcal{Z}^\ast: |Z^\ast| \leq M}$ for some $M > 0$, whence it is compact (as it is a closed subset of a compact set).

@Keen-ameteur I dont know if they are the only weak* compact sets, but from While I ams comment I concluded that we can only consider sets that look like the unit ball (which is symmetric) and extensions of it via a scalar

Also I generally dont understand why scalar multiplication being a homeomorphism implies that the closed ball of any radius in the dual space is weak* compact...

@guest1 The image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact. The closed ball of radius $M$ is the image of the unit ball (which is compact) under the map given by multiplication by $M$ (which is continuous), so it is compact.

@guest1 I’d suggest you review the basics of general topology if you find that confusing. That really should be obvious from basic topology knowledge.

Here is a complete argument, as has already been sketched in the comments. I have broken it up into smaller subparts to be as clear as possible.
Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $C$ be a weak* closed, bounded subset of $X^\ast$.

By the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, $B := \{\ell \in X^\ast : \|\ell\|_{op} \leq 1\}$ is weak* compact.

By the structure of a TVS, the map $s_\lambda : x \mapsto \lambda x$ is a homeomorphism for any $\lambda \neq 0$.

The continuous image of a compact set is compact (this is a general topological fact), so $$s_\lambda(B) = \{\ell \in X^\ast : \|\ell\|_{op} \leq |\lambda|\}$$
is weak* compact.

Since $C$ is bounded, there is some $R > 0$ so that $C \subseteq s_R(B)$. Thus $C$ is a subset of a weak* compact set.

A closed subset of a compact set is compact (this is a general topological fact), and as $C$ is weak* closed and is contained in a weak* compact set, it follows that $C$ is weak* compact.


As you can see, the only "new" things we need to add are these facts from general topology. I am a believer in learning-on-the-go, but working with TVS's requires these kinds of facts to be second nature, as any "trivial" fact about a TVS will probably require some nontrivial general topology.
EDIT: In response to your second question, I want to point out that we don't need two topologies; boundedness is not a topological invariant, so we are really enjoying the rich interplay of the metric structure of the norm, and the topological structure of the weak* topology. That this interplay is worth studying should be justified by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem.

thank you four your exhaustive answer! I have three question thought:
1.) So you define the map $s_{\lambda}$ as a mapping that maps elements from $X$ to $X$ but in your third bullet point you use it as a mapping that maps a subset of $X^$ to another subset of $X^$. So that is unclear to me.
2.) what do we precisley shift with our homeomorphism? Do we take all the elements from the set $B$ and shift them by $\lambda$ and then we know somehow that their norms must be smaller than $\lambda$?

3.) In your edit you say that one does not need two topologies. But we need a normed spaced to invoke the Banach Alaoglu theorem in the first place and then we also need the weak* topology.  So we do need two topologies here right?
4.) you say that boundedness is not a topological invariant. I am not sure what you mean by that? But I think it is important that the boundedness is w.r.t. the norm topology. sorry now these are 4 instead of 3 questions

I do not mean to sound impolite, but the answers to these questions involve “elementary” (relative to the question) skills which should be background to studying the weak* topology. You should try answering these on your own, and if one is particularly confusing you should search Math.SE to see if it’s been asked, and if not, post a question with demonstrated effort.

Well you do sound impolite but I guess that you dont care about that anyway

In fact I don’t think it’s impolite to indicate that certain topics are considered “basic background” for a subject, as it can be a good signal about whether one should return to those topics for review. This is constructive feedback, not criticism.
